# Operator Overload for Template Class Auto Type Conversion

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I have a template class for which I'm overloading `operator+`, but need it to potentially return a different data type than what the class is instantiated for.  For example, the following snippet performs the standard mathematical definition of either vector*vector (inner product), vector*scalar, or scalar*vector.  To be specific, let's say I have a `Vector<int>` and the scalar is of type `double` -- I want to return a double from the "vector*scalar" `operator+` function.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing some `template<class T>` statements for the friend functions(?), but this snippet isn't meant to compile.

```
template<class T>
class Vector
{
private:
    std::vector<T> base;

public:
    friend Vector operator*(const Vector& lhs, const Vector& rhs);  // inner product    
    Vector<T> operator*(const T scalar);  // vector*scalar   
    friend Vector operator*(const T scalar, const Vector& rhs);  // scalar*vector
};

template<class T>
Vector<T> operator*(const Vector<T>& lhs, const Vector<T>& rhs)  // inner product
{
    assert( lhs.base.size() == rhs.base.size() );

    Vector result;
    result.base.reserve(lhs.base.size());
    std::transform( lhs.base.begin(), lhs.base.end(), rhs.base.begin(), std::back_inserter(result.base), std::multiplies<T>() );

    return result;
}

template<class T>
Vector<T> Vector<T>::operator*(const T scalar)  // vector*scalar
{
    Vector result;
    result.base.reserve(base.size());

    std::transform( base.begin(), base.end(), std::back_inserter(result.base), std::bind1st(std::multiplies<T>(), scalar) );

    return result;
}

template<class T>
Vector<T> operator*(const T scalar, const Vector<T>& rhs)  // scalar*vector
{
    Vector result;
    result.base.reserve(rhs.base.size());

    std::transform( rhs.base.begin(), rhs.base.end(), std::back_inserter(result.base), std::bind1st(std::multiplies<T>(), scalar) );

    return result;
}
```

Comment: What is the compiler error message?

Comment: I guess what you want is to return a Vector with the value type being the type returned by the per-component operation, i.e. what `int * double` results in, in this example `double` instead of `int`. That's possible with `decltype`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you want is to return a Vector with the value type being the type returned by the per-component operation, which is not necessarily the type of the scalar.

For example:

```
Vector<int>    * int    -> Vector<int>
Vector<int>    * double -> Vector<double>
Vector<double> * int    -> Vector<double>
Vector<char>   * float  -> Vector<float>
```

etc.

For this, you should define the two input types separately, let's say `T1` and `T2` (and one or two of the operands is a `Vector` of it). You don't want to simply use the scalar type (for vector * scalar, or scalar * vector operation) as the result, otherwise it might be converted (see my 3rd example: The result would then be `Vector<int>`.

The above can be done using `decltype` to find the third (result) type.

For simplicity, define the operator as a non-member:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3 = decltype(std::declval<T1>() * std::declval<T2>())>
Vector<T3> operator*(const Vector<T1>& lhs, const T2 & scalar)  // inner product
{
    Vector<T3> result;
    //...
    return result;
}
```

The interesting part is

```
T3 = decltype(std::declval<T1>() * std::declval<T2>())
```

Here, we find the type `T3` using the other two types `T1` and `T2`. First, we construct two values with unimportant value (the `std::declval` function is a helper function returning the type given as a template parameter). Then we multiply those values, but again the result is unimportant; we're only interested in the type. That's what the third part does: `decltype` gives you the type of the expression (without evaluating it).

The other operators can be implemented analogous.

In order to make those operators friends, you need the syntax

```
template<...> friend ...
```

as seen in [Danvil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819075/operator-overload-for-template-class-auto-type-conversion/20819146#20819146).

Comment: Thanks!  Is it considered good practice to declare this type of thing inline?  (I think that's what you have, anyways)

Comment: Also, I noticed in my code that inside the `operator+` definition I never declare a type for `Vector result`, e.g. I didn't write `Vector<T> result`, but the original code this came from works.  Does a type get implicitly assigned?

Comment: Regarding your first comment: I don't know what you mean with "inline" in this case. The code for the operator definition should go into the header and is always inline since it's a template, like the whole rest of your class. It doesn't matter if you first declare, then define it (in the same header file) or do both things simultaneously. Regarding your second comment: For member functions you can write `Vector` instead of `Vector<T>`, it is equivalent. But for non-members this will not work, you have to be explicit like in my code snippet.

Comment: Thanks again.  I've been getting an error when I attempt to compile using your idea, but it may be with how I'm declaring the function in the class declaration and not the definition.  I'm declaring one such function as `template<class T1, class T2, class T3 = decltype(std::declval<T1>() + std::declval<T2>())>
 friend Vector<T3> operator+(const Vector<T1>& lhs, const Vector<T2>& rhs);` which gives the error  "default template arguments are only allowed on a class template."  Any ideas?

Comment: Oh I just saw that you use `std::multiplies<T>`, which computes `T * T` for the same `T`! You can't use this functor for this. You could use a lambda. Also, when the scalar is on the right hand side, you should bind the scalar to the 2nd operand (or write the lambda accordingly when you switched to lambdas). I'll post you some more code which demonstrates this.

Comment: So I found out what the problem is: When specifying friends, don't give default values for template parameters, that means you should write `template<class T1, class T2, class T3>`. But only for the friend declaration. [**Here is my working code.**](http://ideone.com/em8jP1) I also added those lambdas I was talking about. Do you see how the types need to be respected in the functor? Only then it will behave correct. I didn't test this; if you want to make sure it really works as expected you should add some test code which checks for any overflows.

Comment: Wow, thanks a ton for this.  I'm still getting a compilation error when I try to run your Ideone code on my IDE (Visual C++ 2010 Express) -  error C4519: default template arguments are only allowed on a class template.  This error appears three times and refers to each definition of the `operator*` functions after the class declarations.  Could it have something to do with the implementation I'm using?

Comment: Your compiler is too old. My code makes use of C++11, a newer standard. I doubt that there is another solution to derive `T3` which works with your compiler... But I might be wrong.

Comment: I just had a look: `decltype` is supported in VC++ 2010. It's the template default parameter which makes problems. VC++ 2010 also supports "trailing return types" which can solve the problem. Give me some minutes and I change the code so it *should* work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44103/discussion-between-david-and-leemes)

Answer (score 1):

The friend declaration should look like this:

```
template<class S>
class Vector
{
private:
    std::vector<S> base;

public:
    template<class T> friend T operator*(const Vector<T>& lhs, const Vector<T>& rhs);  // inner product    
    template<class T> friend Vector<T> operator*(const T scalar);  // vector*scalar   
    template<class T> friend Vector<T> operator*(const T scalar, const Vector<T>& rhs);  // scalar*vector
};
```

And the rest of the code like this:

```
template<class T>
T operator*(const Vector<T>& lhs, const Vector<T>& rhs)  // inner product
{
    assert( lhs.base.size() == rhs.base.size() );

    Vector<T> result;
    result.base.reserve(lhs.base.size());
    std::transform( lhs.base.begin(), lhs.base.end(), rhs.base.begin(), std::back_inserter(result.base), std::multiplies<T>() );

    return result;
}

template<class T>
Vector<T> operator*(const Vector<T>& lhs, const T scalar)  // vector*scalar
{
    return scalar*lhs;
}

template<class T>
Vector<T> operator*(const T scalar, const Vector<T>& rhs)  // scalar*vector
{
    Vector<T> result;
    result.base.reserve(rhs.base.size());

    std::transform( rhs.base.begin(), rhs.base.end(), std::back_inserter(result.base), std::bind1st(std::multiplies<T>(), scalar) );

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a benefit to declaring the second "vector*scalar" a friend, even though it would be called on an object of the class?

Answer (score 0):

You can add more template parameters as such:

```
template<class T, class S>
Vector<S> Vector<T>::operator*(const S scalar)
```

and make sure you use `S` for the scalar type and `T` for the vector element type in the correct places in the function body.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to do this so that the result is always the "higher" of the two data types, whether it is the vector or the scalar?  It seems like this would only return the data type that the scalar object is, but what if the vector was a double and the scalar an int?